# Looking for ehCache embedded server example

Tags: java, ehcache

I have not been able to find any documentation on how to setup an ehCache server embedded inside an existing application. Does anyone know of a way of doing this?

Comment: can you share a bit more detail on what you're trying to achieve with ehcache server?

Answer (score 1):

It is working not as a server but it is simple library. In this case usage is pretty simple:
http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/code-samples.html

All you need - configure ehcache.xml.

Yes, there is also a [server](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/modules/cache-server.html), in form of separate web-app. So you can just take this web-app and run on embdeded jetty.